# Got unexpected error of "NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineUnloadException" after the nunit test case running successful

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-console

I'm running nunit test case with C# code, every time, the case is passed, but in the output log, I can see below error:
NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineUnloadException : Agent Process was terminated successfully after error.
----> NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineUnloadException : Exception encountered unloading application domain
----> NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException : Exception encountered unloading application domain: Error while unloading appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131015)
Application domain name: domain-

And I don't know where is this error from? I can't figure out the reason. Does anyone can help?

Run nunit test case with C# code. But got error after the case running successful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.